# TFS - Editing a checkin-note on checkins made before the creation of the checkin-note on

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I added a checkin note (required) recently, but i need to add this information on previous checkins. However, when i view a previous checkin through 'view history', the note field does not show, i can only edit the comment. It does show on new checkins though.

This is how i try to edit the checkin:

```
Right click on a file on Source Control Explorer -> View History -> Right click a changeset -> Changeset Details
```

I'm on TFS 2013, using VS2013.

Comment: Are you viewing the check-in on the history page or are you right-clicking on the changeset and choosing "Changeset Details"?

Comment: Right click on a file on Source Control Explorer -> View History -> Right click a changeset -> Changeset Details